# How to jungle effectively with Wukong, using its decoy ability?

Tags: league-of-legends

When I jungle with Wukong I sometimes find it hard for the jungle monsters to **focus my decoy rather than me**. Maybe I'm wrong but if *position myself poorly* (too close to the monsters maybe?), monsters will begin to ignore my clone and focus back on me which is unintented.

So, how to jungle effectively with wukong, using its decoy?
If I may ask a sub question: should I take decoy second or the Q (knowing I would begin to jungle with E)?

Comment: nightblue3 sometimes jungles with wukong. he explains what he's doing very well IMHO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jungling with Wukong became a lot harder with the introduction of the new jungle. He didn't have the fastest clearing speed before and now he even has some trouble with the incoming damage (and the camps also recieved a HP buff).

All this makes a correct usage of Decoy important. Note that jungle Camps always focus the **closest unit if they are in combat**. Because this your best chances of getting the jungle creeps to focus your clone is by simply walking as far away as possible. Using your E will teleport you **into the targeted unit** which automatically makes you the closest target so try to use your decoy after your buff from your E ran out (you won't lose any attacks on the creep like this).

Keep in mind that the current Summoners Rift map is still in beta and I've seen a lot of jungle minions bugging around.

For your second question: Usually you should go with `E -> Q -> W` for more damage output but taking W second also works as a tiny survivability boost.

Comment: you are even focused when you're the nearest target out of combat, then entering combat of course.

Comment: @DropDeadSander-EUW Oh yeah... I just realized a part of the answer didn't make it from my mind to the actual post :P I'll fix that.